# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization in App.js at export default App line

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my Chat Web App. I implemented a socket.io listener ("start-chat")  and in the listener I added three asyncThunk functions using dispatch conditionally then suddenly an error appear in my console and my program stopped working, it was this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaNxV.png)
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization`

I implemented listener in the DashboardLayout.js and here is code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack } from "@mui/material";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { connectSocket, socket } from "../../socket";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import {
  addDirectConversation,
  updateDirectConversation,
} from "../../Redux/slices/conversation/conversation";
import { SelectConversation } from "../../Redux/slices/app/app";

const DashboardLayout = () => {
  const { isLoggedIn, userId } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { conversations } = useSelector((state)=>state.conversation.directChat);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      window.onload = function () {
        if (!window.location.hash) {
          window.location = window.location + "#loaded";
          window.location.reload();
        }
      };

      window.onload();

      if (!socket) {
        connectSocket(userId);
      }

      socket.on("new-friend-request", (data) => {
        toast(data.message, {
          icon: "",
          style: {
            borderRadius: "10px",
            background: "#333",
            color: "#fff",
          },
        });
      });
      socket.on("request-accepted", (data) => {
        toast(data.message, {
          icon: "",
          style: {
            borderRadius: "10px",
            background: "#333",
            color: "#fff",
          },
        });
      });
      socket.on("request-sent", (data) => {
        toast(data.message, {
          icon: "",
          style: {
            borderRadius: "10px",
            background: "#333",
            color: "#fff",
          },
        });
      });
      socket.on("start-chat", (data) => {
        const existingConversation = conversations.find(
          (el) => el.id === data.id
        );
        if (existingConversation) {
          dispatch(updateDirectConversation({ conversation: data }));
        } else {
          // add direct conversation
          dispatch(addDirectConversation({ conversation: data }));
        }
        dispatch(SelectConversation({ roomId: data.id }));
      });
    }

    return () => {
      socket?.off("new-friend-request");
      socket?.off("request-accepted");
      socket?.off("request-sent");
      socket?.off("start-chat");
    };

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isLoggedIn, userId ]);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to={"/auth/login"} />;
  }

  return (
    <Stack direction={"row"}>
      {/* SideBar */}
      <SideBar />
      <Outlet />
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

Here is SideBar.js:

```
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Divider,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Stack,
  useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Gear } from "phosphor-react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useSettings from "../../hooks/useSettings";
import AntSwitch from "../../components/AntSwitch";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import logo from "../../assets/Images/logo.ico";
import { Nav_Buttons, Profile_Menu } from "../../data";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../../Redux/slices/auth/authSlice";

const getPath = (index) => {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return "/app";
    case 1:
      return "/group";
    case 2:
      return "/call";
    case 3:
      return "/settings";
    default:
      return;
  }
};

function SideBar() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { onToggleMode } = useSettings();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const getMenuPath = (index) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return "/profile";
      case 1:
        return "/settings";
      case 2:
        dispatch(logout());
        return "/auth/login";
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      p={2}
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        boxShadow: "0px 0px 2px",
        height: "100vh",
        width: 100,
      }}
    >
      <Stack
        direction={"column"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
        sx={{ height: "100%" }}
        spacing={3}
      >
        <Stack alignItems={"center"} spacing={4}>
          {/* logo box  */}
          <Box
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
              height: 64,
              width: 64,
              borderRadius: 1.5,
            }}
          >
            <img src={logo} alt="Chat App Logo" />
          </Box>
          {/* end logo box  */}

          {/* Button icon box  */}
          <Stack
            sx={{ width: "max-content" }}
            direction={"column"}
            alignItems={"center"}
            spacing={3}
          >
            {Nav_Buttons.map((el) =>
              el.index === selected ? (
                <Box
                  key={el.index}
                  sx={{
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                    borderRadius: 1.5,
                  }}
                >
                  <IconButton sx={{ width: "max-content", color: "#fff" }}>
                    {el.icon}
                  </IconButton>
                </Box>
              ) : (
                <IconButton
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelected(el.index);
                    navigate(getPath(el.index));
                  }}
                  key={el.index}
                  sx={{
                    width: "max-content",
                    color: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#000" : "#fff",
                  }}
                >
                  {el.icon}
                </IconButton>
              )
            )}
            <Divider sx={{ width: "48px" }} />
            {selected === 3 ? (
              <Box
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                  borderRadius: 1.5,
                }}
              >
                <IconButton sx={{ width: "max-content", color: "#fff" }}>
                  <Gear />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            ) : (
              <IconButton
                onClick={() => {
                  setSelected(3);
                  navigate(getPath(3));
                }}
                sx={{
                  width: "max-content",
                  color: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#000" : "#fff",
                }}
              >
                <Gear />
              </IconButton>
            )}
          </Stack>
          {/* End button icon box  */}
        </Stack>

        <Stack spacing={4}>
          <AntSwitch
            onChange={() => {
              onToggleMode();
            }}
            defaultChecked
          />
          <Avatar
            src={faker.image.avatar()}
            id="basic-button"
            aria-controls={open ? "basic-menu" : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
            onClick={handleClick}
            size={20}
            sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          />
          <Menu
            id="basic-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            MenuListProps={{
              "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
            }}
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "right" }}
            transformOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "left" }}
          >
            <Stack direction={"column"} spacing={1} px={1}>
              {Profile_Menu.map((el, idx) => (
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>
                  <Stack
                    sx={{ width: 100 }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      navigate(getMenuPath(idx));
                    }}
                    direction={"row"}
                    alignItems={"center"}
                    justifyContent={"space-between"}
                  >
                    <span>{el.title}</span>
                    {el.icon}
                  </Stack>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Stack>
          </Menu>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

Here is App.js

```
// routes
import Router from "./routes";
// theme
import ThemeProvider from "./theme";
// components
import ThemeSettings from "./components/settings";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Toaster position="top-right" reverseOrder={true} />
      <ThemeSettings>
        {" "}
        <Router />{" "}
      </ThemeSettings>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here index.js

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HelmetProvider } from "react-helmet-async";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

// contexts
import SettingsProvider from "./contexts/SettingsContext";
import { store } from "./Redux/store";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <ReduxProvider store={store} >
        <SettingsProvider>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </SettingsProvider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

this is Router.js

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { Navigate, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";

// layouts
import DashboardLayout from "../layouts/dashboard";
import MainLayout from "../layouts/main";

// config
import { DEFAULT_PATH } from "../config";
import LoadingScreen from "../components/LoadingScreen";

const Loadable = (Component) => (props) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/auth',
      element: <MainLayout/>,
      children: [
        {path: 'login', element: <LoginPage />},
        {path: 'register', element: <RegisterPage />},
        {path: 'reset-password', element: <ResetPasswordPage />},
        {path: 'new-password', element: <NewPasswordPage />},
        {path: 'verify', element: <VerifyPage />},
      ]
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to={DEFAULT_PATH} replace />, index: true },
        { path: "app", element: <GeneralApp /> },
        { path: "settings", element: <Settings /> },
        { path: "group", element: <GroupPage /> },
        { path: "call", element: <CallPage /> },
        { path: "profile", element: <ProfilePage /> },

        { path: "404", element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
      ],
    },
    { path: "*", element: <Navigate to="/404" replace /> },
  ]);
}

const GeneralApp = Loadable(
  lazy(() => import("../pages/dashboard/GeneralApp"))
);
const Settings = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/dashboard/Settings")));
const LoginPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/Login")));
const RegisterPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/Register")));
const ResetPasswordPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/ResetPassword")));
const NewPasswordPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/NewPassword")));
const VerifyPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/verify")));
const GroupPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/dashboard/Group")));
const CallPage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/dashboard/Call")));
const ProfilePage = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/dashboard/Profile")));
const Page404 = Loadable(lazy(() => import("../pages/Page404")));


export default Router
```

path.js

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

function path(root, sublink) {
  return `${root}${sublink}`;
}

const ROOTS_DASHBOARD = "/";

export const PATH_DASHBOARD = {
  root: ROOTS_DASHBOARD,
  general: {
    app: path(ROOTS_DASHBOARD, "app"),
  },
};
```

Also full frontend code git link:
https://github.com/mo-amir-code/Tawky-Chat-Web-App

I don't know why this error happenning, Please anyone provide a solution? Thanks